# Interfacing TTP229 touch sensor with arduino and gsm module

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I have been working on an Arduino based call and message project which I am following from this link https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/call-and-message-using-arduino-sim900-gsm.
This project uses a membrane keypad for inputting the phone number and etc., but I intend to use a TTP229 16 channel Touch sensor module.

I need help in taking input from the touchpad rather than the keypad. As I need to submit the project within a month it is my humble request if someone can help.
Thanks for replying!

Comment: how does the touch panel communicate with the arduino?  ..... what code are you using? ..... what problems are you facing?

Comment: It communicates over serial im using the below code to get the data from the sensor.http://forum.hobbycomponents.com/viewtopic.php?f=73&t=1781&hilit=hcmodu0079

Comment: I am able to fetch the data from the sensor but i am not able to call that function in the main gsm program.